# Ionic remote debugging not showing the app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

Hey Im trying to Remote debug an Ionic Application, it was working recently, but now the device shows on Chrome Remote devices but when i click the device the app process wont show. it will show other mobile chrome tab Processes but not the Ionic app.

any clues ?

Comment: Did you recently add a buildkey to your application? The reason i'm asking:
https://github.com/jrstarke/webview-debug/issues/4#issuecomment-234096667
(might or might not be related to your issue)

also be sure you launch the devices from your computer using the ionic cordova command.

Then go to :
chrome://inspect/#devices

Comment: I fixed this, It was my fault, I built a release apk and was expecting a debug mode. When you build without the --release, It works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this, It was my fault, I built a release apk and was expecting a debug mode. When you build without the --release, It works

Comment: You save my day dude!